# PhpStorm with JSDoc OOP problems

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

As I am not sure which responsibilities are taken by JSDoc and which by PhpStorm, I just describe a problem.

Imagine a simple class inheritance. All works fine except static method. You can see an example:

[image: Static methods problem]

As you can see `B.s` is not marked by PhpStorm as an inherited from `A.s`. And it is not marked by JSDoc with `Overrides: A.s`. Object methods (`a`) work nice. Another problem is that PhpStorm does not show upper arrow new `function B` as it shows for `this.a`. But it is only for start. Follow up.

It is very unlikely that you have all classes in one file. And I move class `A` into a separate file. Now it works well. But when I add a namespace problems appear. See `A.js`:

[image: Namespace problem]

And `B.js`:

[image: B.js]

As you can see. Now PhpStorm tells us only about `A#a` <> `B#a` connections.

So how can I solve these problems? Hacks are welcome.

Comment: Added `webstorm` tag as it's shares the same JS code (PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB)

Comment: JSdoc doesn't support static members inheritance - see https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/433, https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1229. And I can't suggest any workarounds for PhpStorm:(